# Stepping through a range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am probably misunderstanding some of the basics, but I am trying to replace erroneous formulas by using replace.
The one in a single cell seems to work, but the one that is a group of cells I am struggling with

```
    var W2X = AllShts[b].getRange("O18").getFormula();
    AllShts[b].getRange('O18').setValue(W2X.replace("W","X"));
    c=c+1

    var rngN18_29 = AllShts[b].getRange("N18:N29");
    for (var a = 0; a < rngN18_29.getNumRows(); a++) {
      var r = rngN18_29.getNumRows();
      var x = rngN18_29[a].getA1Notation();
      var rngN = rngN18_29[a].getFormula();
      rngN18_29[a].setValue(rngN.replace("V","W"));
      c=c+1
    };
```

I have set the variable rngN18_29 using getRange

To step through each cell I have tried to use a for statement, using the number of rows as a count for the iterations.  Checking this with variable r, this seems to be correct.

I am unable however to get rngN18_29[a] to look at the cell I want.  I get the error Cannot read property 'getA1Notation' of undefined (same with getFormula)

For now I am most interested in how I would step through the range N18:N29
As an aside, is it possible to do the replace on the entire range at once (changing formulas rather than values)?

> Edit:

Following TheMaster's advice, I have the following which seems to do the trick.
Many thanks Sir!

```
var rngN18_29 = AllShts[b].getRange("N18:N29").getFormulas();
for (var a = 0; a < rngN18_29.length; a++) {      
  rngN18_29[a][0] = rngN18_29[a][0].replace("V","W");
}
AllShts[b].getRange("N18:N29").setFormulas(rngN18_29);
```

Comment: Step through it's values instead. `var values = AllShts[b].getRange("N18:N29").getValues();` OR `var formls = AllShts[b].getRange("N18:N29").getFormulas()`. Modify the array and set it back in one shot. Read best practices in documentation. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for more details.

Comment: Would i then use `AllShts[b].getRange("N18:N29")[a].setValue` to change the original formula to the new one?  I couldn't work out how to assign the individual cell as rngN18_29[a] was creating an error.  Thanks

Comment: You would change the array `formls`: `formls[a][0] = formls[a][0].replace("v","w")`. Finally, range.setformulas(formls)

Comment: Please refer to [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) whenever you found a solution to your problem. @TheMaster consider create an answer so it can be accepted and upvoted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step through it's values instead.  Modify the array and set it back in one shot.

```
var rngN18_29 = AllShts[b].getRange("N18:N29")
var formulas = rngN18_29.getFormulas();
for (var a = 0; a < formulas.length; a++) {      
   formulas[a][0] =  formulas[a][0].replace("V","W");
}
rngN18_29.setFormulas(formulas);
```

[Best practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations)